# make Notification with RemoteViews cancelable

Tags: android, notifications

i'm building a notification for my Player using RemoteViews.
I want the user to be able to remove the notification(both from lockscreen and when it's unlocked) and stop the player when that is done. How can i achieve that?
Here is the code where i build it:

```
public void buildNotification(String action) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        previousIntent.setAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
        PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, previousIntent, 0);

        Intent rewindIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        previousIntent.setAction(ACTION_REWIND);
        PendingIntent prewindIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, rewindIntent, 0);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        playIntent.setAction(action);
        PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, playIntent, 0);

        Intent forwardIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        playIntent.setAction(ACTION_FAST_FORWARD);
        PendingIntent pforwardIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, forwardIntent, 0);

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        nextIntent.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
        PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, nextIntent, 0);




        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_prev, ppreviousIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_rewind, prewindIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_pause, pplayIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_forward, pforwardIntent);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_next, pnextIntent);




        //views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_collapse, pcloseIntent);

        MainActivity m = MainActivity.sInstance;

        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgbtn_prev, android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous);

        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgbtn_rewind, android.R.drawable.ic_media_rew);

        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgbtn_pause, action.equals(ACTION_PAUSE) ?
                android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause : android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgbtn_forward, android.R.drawable.ic_media_ff);

        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgbtn_next, android.R.drawable.ic_media_next);


        String s = Player.getInstance().song.getName();
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.filename, s.substring(0,s.length()-4));


        Notification status = new Notification.Builder(this).build();
        status.contentView = views;
        status.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        status.icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        status.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        startForeground(1, status);
    }
```

btw, `contentView` and `icon` seem to be deprecated, how should i do that instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Notification buildNotification(String action) {

        //...

    Notification status = new Notification.Builder(this).build();
    status.contentView = views;
    status.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    status.icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    status.contentIntent = pendingIntent;

    return status;
}
```

On Play start notification like

```
startForeground(1, buildNotification):
```

And on Pause just notify, then it will be removable.

```
notificationManager.notify(1, buildNotification);
```